# can any body set this image with 9-patch in android

Tags: android

[image]

I tried but the side round shape not shaped properly with [9-patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html).

Comment: Great, i also want my applications images with 9-patch, can anybody make for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

9-patch is a simple png image with 1-pixel borders indicating stretchable area. Read [more](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.htm).

Comment: ok. but i want that kind of image in 9-patch will is possible?

Comment: so the round corner or round side in 9-patch is not posible?

Comment: Not, it's possible. My png could have rounded corners.

Answer (score 1):

[image]This should solve your purpose.